# How to restore a changed native python file?

Tags: python, windows

I have accidentally overwritten a native python file (Python\Python310\Lib\wave.py). I cant restore it through Windows.

Is there a clever way to restore it? I was thinking to reinstall Python, but Im afraid that I might need to reinstall all my packages, which would be a pain. Are there other options?

Comment: replace this file for python3.10 extract?

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you mean

Comment: overwrite with orignal file

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by finding the native Python source code through https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommed you to reinstall or repair Python.

[image: Repair Python]

And to ease your pain from reinstalling the modules, you can use the below to save all modules names with version.

```
pip freeze >a.txt
```

Then after reinstalling use

```
pip install -r a.txt
```

This would install all the module in the text. For more detail you can use `pip install -help`

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank you. As for the Repairing, i tried that, but it didn't fix the broken file.